# background-color of dashed borders

Tags: css, border, background-color

I currently have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="content">...</div>
    <div id="footer">...</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#content, #footer {
    background: #fff;
}

#footer {
    border-top: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

**Note:** `holder` doesn't have any `background-color`

---

My concern is that the background of the top border on the `footer` will be transparent since `holder` doesn't have any background.

And applying a white background to the `holder` is not an option in my case (I won't explain why not, but trust me, it is not possible)

**My Question:**

- The background of the dashed border will be the same of my `footer`
  (white) or the background-color of `holder` (none)?
- Will it behave cross-browser the same way all the time?

Comment: What did your *tests* produce? Which browsers did you test?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Google Chrome, and it looks as expected (white background). But I really fear it won't be the same output on all browsers. So I was looking for some kind of documentation or experts advice to relieve my fears

Comment: Borders don't have background colors - they're transparent in these regions. They take on the colour of whatever is behind them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The border belongs to your #footer div and will render with its background attribute - clear or otherwise.
2. I've tested the following CSS in Chrome, Safari, Firefox (sorry, no immediate IE access):

   ```
   * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

   #content, #footer { background: #fff; }

   #content { background:#00F; }

   #footer {
       border-top: 5px dashed #f00;
   }
   ```

Please let me know if I missed your question, but I believe this is what you were asking.

> The background style of the content, padding, and border areas of a box is specified by the 'background' property of the generating element. Margin backgrounds are always transparent.

via http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html